# How to fix shared libraries errors?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, shared-libraries

I moved a HDD with Ubuntu 14.04 from my PC to a laptop. It boots without problems but it's stuck on the login screen. If I enter my password it will go back to the login screen. If I log in via terminal (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>) I get the following errors (just after *Welcome to Ubuntu...*):

```
apt-config: error while loading shared libraries /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.4.12: invalid ELF header
import.im6: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/368
/usr/bin/lsb_release: 30: /usr/bin/lsb_release: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I booted from a live usb and tried `fsck` but it gave no errors.

Both computers have Intel CPUs.

If I put the HDD back in the PC from which I took it I get the same errors now.

What can I do to fix it?

**Edit:**

It seems that most commands give this errors:

- wget

  ```
  error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0: invalid ELF header
  ```
- ssh

  ```
  error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: invalid ELF header
  ```
- firefox (just tried to see what I get)

  ```
  error while loading shared libraries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: invalid ELF header
  ```

Comment: Is your laptop also 64 bits? `invalid ELF header` probably indicates the wrong architecture.

Comment: Yes. The PC has an i3 and the laptop a Celeron (one of the new versions).